# How to wait for Tasks to finish with Task.WhenAll ?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

This all works so far but there are 2 things that bother me and I think I am using the wrong way

Problem #1 - I only want to return a string but I seem forced to return a string ARRAY. How can I just make this return a string ?

```
   Task<string> taskVelocifyData = GetVelocifyData();
            string[] userEmail = await Task.WhenAll(taskVelocifyData);
```

Problem #2 - Not sure if this is a problem but is this the optimal to wait for async tasks to complete before going to the next async task ?

```
  private async void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        List<string>[] photos = new List<string>[10];

        try
        {
            //Use Velocify API to get most recent lead
            Task<string> taskVelocifyData = GetVelocifyData();
            string[] userEmail = await Task.WhenAll(taskVelocifyData);

            //Ignore recent lead if it has not changed
            if (lsi.VelocifyLeadTitle != previousVelocifyLeadTitle)
            {
                //If there is an email, use FullContact API to get photos
                if (userEmail[0] != "")
                {
                    var taskFullContactData = GetFullContactData(userEmail[0]);
                     photos = await Task.WhenAll(taskFullContactData);

                    if (photos.Count() != 0)
                    {
                        var taskFaceData = GetFaceData(photos);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    lsi.FullContactPictures = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                }

                // DEBUG
                //   dispatcherTimer.Stop();

                LeadSpeakerItems.Add(lsi);

                SpeakData(leadSpeakerItems.Last().VelocifyLeadTitle);
            }

            previousVelocifyLeadTitle = lsi.VelocifyLeadTitle;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Task.WhenAny()` or directly await one Task ? If you only want to wait for one Task then wait for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a single `Task`, so you can `await` it directly. You don't need `Task.WhenAll`.

```
string userEmail = await GetVelocifyData();
```

The [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx) method

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the System.Threading.Tasks.Task objects in an enumerable collection have completed.

When completed, the task will return an array with results of all tasks passed to `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: I would add that `Task.WhenAll` is meant for arrays of tasks not single tasks to the answer.

Comment: @toadflakz I was just adding it. Quite slowly, as I'm in the middle of my dinner

Comment: @Jakub Why are you answering questions in the middle of dinner? :X

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I must have grabbed my keyboard instead of a fork by accident :)

Comment: wow that was easy.. I ended up down the path of using Task Class when initially methods were running at the same time.. I must have been missing a await/async